# Converting an iterative function into recursive

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

One of the hardest concepts I've found in programming has been recursion. I have been trying to convert this function into a recursive call for 2 days now, but I just can't get it to work. Its a delete function for a BST

```
public void deleteByMerging(T el) {
    BSTNode<T> tmp, node, p = root, prev = null;
    while (p != null && !p.el.equals(el)) {  // find the node p
         prev = p;                           // with element el;
         if (el.compareTo(p.el) < 0)
              p = p.right;
         else p = p.left;
    }
    node = p;
    if (p != null && p.el.equals(el)) {
         if (node.right == null) // node has no right child: its left
              node = node.left;  // child (if any) is attached to its parent;
         else if (node.left == null) // node has no left child: its right
              node = node.right; // child is attached to its parent;
         else {                  // be ready for merging subtrees;
              tmp = node.left;   // 1. move left
              while (tmp.right != null) // 2. and then right as far as
                  tmp = tmp.right;      //    possible;
              tmp.right =        // 3. establish the link between
                  node.right;    //    the rightmost node of the left
                                 //    subtree and the right subtree;
              node = node.left;  // 4.
         }
         if (p == root)
              root = node;
         else if (prev.left == p)
              prev.left = node;
         else prev.right = node; // 5.
    }
    else if (root != null)
         System.out.println("el " + el + " is not in the tree");
    else System.out.println("the tree is empty");
}
```

I got it as far as to find the node,  but steps 1 through 5 (in comments) really breaks my brain.

Comment: 'if (el.compareTo(p.el) < 0) p = p.right;' A bit confused with this code. If el is less than p.el, then search right? Why? Unless the compareTo function isn't implemented the 'normal' way.

Comment: well i got this code from a data struct and algorithms book i bought.  http://www.mathcs.duq.edu/drozdek/DSinJava/BST.java  thats the whole implementation

Comment: I think this is an error. If you look at deleteByCopying(), it has the correct behaviour. But this is not related to your problem of converting it to recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to "find" the node. Let's try to think in recursive way:

`function find(el, p)
      if p == null, not found! (return p, i.e. null)
      if p.el == el, found! (return p)
      if el < p.el, return find(el, p.right)
      if el > p.el, return find(el, p.left)`

This is recursive, right? So, `BSTNode<T> node = find(el, root)` will return either the node that matches el or return null which implies NOT FOUND.

The remaining delete by merge only manages object reference, so I'm not to comment.

Comment: PS: That's a pseudo code, not a real Java code piece. Just to illustrate how to think in recursive way.

Comment: well the find is easy enough but what im struggling with is the bit that is "// 1. move left" in the commented code

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with the merging algorithm steps 3 and 4. Imagine you are deleting a node with left and right subtree. The empty space is replaced with a node that must satisfy the BST condition (ie. greater than left node and smaller than right node). That replacement node is found in the rightmost left subtree (Step 2 of comments). That node is pointed to by tmp. So now we have "node" which points to the node being deleted and "tmp" which points to the replacement node. In Step 3, this is where the linking happens.

```
tmp.right = node.right
tmp.left = node.left    // missing from the algorithm
```

Now in Step 4, this is where the "node" variable is changed to point to the replacement node "tmp" so in Step 5, the previous node "prev" can link to the replacement node. I believe Step 4 should be

```
node = tmp;
```

instead of

```
node = node.left;
```

Please check if my analysis is correct. Maybe that's why you're not able to understand what's going on. The recursive part of the deleteByMerging() is the searching for the node to delete. Once found, the algorithm to merge the tree would not change.